# Permission problem to create AWS EC2 IAM ROLE FOR S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

In my company, my AWS IAM access is restricted; I only  have access to AWS as a Federated user: AWSReservedSSO_PowerUserAcces.

I want to use AWS Cloudformation to create an IAM role for an EC2 instance such that the ec2 can copy files from an S3 bucket. What kind of permissions/policies/roles should I request from the AWS Cloud Administrator in my company?

I tried this Cloudformation code but got an error that I don't have the right to create an InstanceProfile

```
  ## IAM Roles/Policies 
  # Assigning an IAM role to the webServer(s)(EC2 instance(s)) that allows it to access S3 .


  S3BucketRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub ${ProjectName}-Role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: '/'

  # An IAM instance profile
  S3BucketInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: '/'
      Roles:
        - Ref: S3BucketRole

  # this IAM policy permits the webServer(s)(EC2 instance(s)) to list items in S3
  S3BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: S3BucketPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:Get*
              - s3:List*
            Resource:
              - arn:aws:s3:::iac-webappbucket
              - arn:aws:s3:::iac-webappbucket/*
      Roles:
        - Ref: S3BucketRole
```